# How do I get the driver for my graphics card?

Tags: drivers, 13.10, graphics

I would like to get the correct driver for my graphics card. I am running Ubuntu 13.10. I think I have an  ATI Radeon HD4200 integrated graphics chip, but when I go into system details, Ubuntu says the driver is "Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880." Is this the correct driver? If not, how can I install the correct one?
P.S. I am a total Ubuntu newbie, have used MS Windows all my life. Step by step explanations please

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to install driver for my AMD Radeon HD8570 too. I found this helpful:

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

I have tried several ways in that post and pages it refers, among which I found the answer "Installing the ATI Catalyst Drivers for 13.04" in that post suits my situation (ubuntu 12.04.4, 64bit OS) at the best. And it is the most simple one I have ever tried, although I can pass the installation test only before I restart my system (once restarted, both fglxinfo and fgl_glxgears would result in the same error).